# MQTT - Publish a message to many independent topics

Tags: messaging, publish-subscribe, mqtt

In MQTT, A Client can subscribe to a Topic Name or a Topic Wildcard. A message can be  published to a topic or some topics with the same wildcard. But how to publish a message to some topic which are independent to each other? Do I need to modify MQTT Protocol?

For Example: My server handle connections from 10 clients(these client do not relate to each other) with the ids : client1, client2, ..., client 10, and client1 want to send a message to an arbitrary number of clients(e.g. client 3, client 7, client8)

Answer (score 6):

You can only publish to a specific topic, not a wildcard topic or to a client id.

Subscriptions can be to wild card or specific topics.

Multiple clients can subscribe to the same topics so if you want to send a message to a group of clients then you just need to pick a topic they are all subscribed to. Or there is nothing to stop you publishing the same message to multiple topics in sequences.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the question. A client can publish a message to multiple topics in sequences, but the server will need to handle many incoming messages instead of only one message

Comment: Unless you are publishing messages at incredible high rates this won't be a problem

Comment: For example: I've worked with GCM(Google Cloud Messaging), it allows sending a message to 1000 devices.  if I build an application similar to GCM using MQTT, When a client wants to send a message to 1000 devices, it needs to send 1000 separate messages with the same content, and the server needs to process 1000 incoming messages(imagine if they are tls messages). Is this a big overhead?

Comment: Or just have all clients subscribe to a broadcast topic as well as a client specific topic, then you only have to publish once

Comment: If the message to publish is big, you incur the bandwidth for each clone of the message.